# Vector Functions of One Variable

Tags: linear-algebra, graphing-functions, vector-analysis

Question

A particle moves along the curve of the intersection of the cylinders $y=-x^2$ and $z=x^2$ in the direction in which $x$ increases. (All distances are in cm.) At the instant when the particle is at the point $(1,\,-1,\,1)$ its speed is $9$ cm/s, and the speed is increasing at a rate of $3$ cm/s$^2$. Find the velocity and acceleration of particle at that instant.

Solution (Well at least my attempt at one)

$\mathbf{r}(t) = x\mathbf{i} - x^2\mathbf{j} + x^2\mathbf{k}$

$\mathbf{v}(t) = \left(\mathbf{i} - 2x\mathbf{j} + 2x\mathbf{k}\right)\dfrac{dx}{dt}$

\begin{align*}
\implies ||\mathbf{v}|| &=\left(\sqrt{1^2 +4x^2+4x^2}\right) \left|\dfrac{d x}{dt}\right|\\
&=(\sqrt{1+8x^2})\dfrac{dx}{dt}
\end{align*}

$|\frac{dx}{dt}|=\frac{dx}{dt}$ since the particle is always increasing

$\implies$ at the point $(1,\,-1,\,1),\,\, ||\mathbf{v}|| = 9$, so $dx/dt = 3$ and the velocity at that point is 
$\mathbf{v}(t) = 3\mathbf{i} - 6\mathbf{j} + 6\mathbf{k}$

Now acceleration is where I have a bit of trouble

$\mathbf{a}(t) =\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}(\mathbf{i} - 2x\mathbf{j} + 2x\mathbf{k}) + (\dfrac{dx}{dt})^2(- 2\mathbf{j} + 2\mathbf{k})$

But I don't exactly know what to do from here any help would be appreciated

Comment: Those aren't cylinders.

Comment: I guess you need to use your equation for $||v||$, and differentiate it with respect to $t$. You know that this is increasing at 3cm/s$^2$, so you'll have an equation to give you d$^2$x/dt$^2$, which is all you're missing.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that, at the given instant:
$x=1$  cm and
\begin{align*}
\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}&=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{v}{\sqrt{1+8x^2}}\right)\qquad\text{where }v=||\mathbf{v}||\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{1+8x^2}\dfrac{dv}{dt}-\frac{8x}{\sqrt{1+8x^2}}\frac{dx}{dt}v}{1+8x^2} \\
&=\frac{\sqrt{1+8(1)^2}(3)-\dfrac{8(1)}{\sqrt{1+8(1)^2}}(3)(9)}{1+8(1)^2}\text{ cm/s}^2\\
&=\frac{9-72}{9}\text{ cm/s}^2\\
\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}&=-7\text{ cm/s}^2
\end{align*}
Hence, at the given instant,
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{a}&=\left(-7 \text{ cm/s}^2\right)(\mathbf{i}-2\mathbf{j}+2\mathbf{k} \text{ cm/s})+(9 \text{ cm/s})^2(-2\mathbf{j}+2\mathbf{k}\text{ cm}^{-1})\\
&=-7\mathbf{i}-4\mathbf{j}+4\mathbf{k}\quad\text{cm/s}^2
\end{align*}

Comment: $|\mathbf{a}|=\sqrt{1259}=35.4\neq 3$.  So I don't think this can be correct...

Comment: @DrXorile: I have corrected it, my first post was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment above, you can figure out $\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}$ from your equation in $|\mathbf{v}|$, given that you know that the change of speed is 3cm/s/s.

\begin{eqnarray}
|\mathbf{v}| &=& (\sqrt{1+8x^2})\dfrac{dx}{dt}\\
\dfrac{d|\mathbf{v}|}{dt} &=& (\sqrt{1+8^2})\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} + \frac{8x}{\sqrt{1+8x^2}}\left(\dfrac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 = 3 \\
\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} &=& -7
\end{eqnarray}

Plugging this into your equation for $\mathbf{a}$ gives 
\begin{equation}\mathbf{a} = -7\mathbf{i} - 4\mathbf{j} + 4\mathbf{k}\end{equation}
and it can easily be checked that $|\mathbf{a}|=3$